# How to address with the boss that I need work permit for a psychologist?

Tags: communication, management, psychology, italy

I'm a developer, in Italy, and due to some problems related to my social sphere with friends I've started going to a psychologist.
The problem is that the one that I found and is helping me is only available during working hours.
I have work permits to use when I need and many hours left to cover my needing, but in 1/2 months those will become weekly appointments of 1/2 hours off from work.
How can I address this issue with my boss explaining that this is not related to work, but only to my social sphere in my private life?

I'm worried that this will cause a lack of esteem against me.

Comment: A location would be helpful for getting a meaningful answer.

Comment: By permit do you just mean "permission to be off from work" to get to your appointments? Is there any reason you need to disclose the type of appointment? Wouldn't "I have a standing medical appointment" be enough of an answer? Why does your boss need to know you'll be seeing a psychotherapist?

Comment: A medical visit is a medical visit. Kind, type or reason for one is not interest to your employee. Just state you need to see a doctor once every week.

Comment: Please add a country tag. The way this is handled (and protected) varies A LOT by country

Comment: Tell your boss that you have a mistress and visit her once a week. He won't ask any more question after that.

Comment: Simply state that you have a regular **Doctor's appointment**.   You would never, ever say anything about your medical problem, what sort of doctor, why you are going to the doctor, etc.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm overthinking it.
This is caused by the fact that everyone in the company is really friendly, but that causes a lack of private life sometimes.
Thanks to the smart working I've been able to leave the work without noticing except for my boss that approved my work permit and asked nothing.
But for sure I will be asked when I will say that this will be a weekly appointment, that's why I was asking.
Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: The only problem it could arise, if one is going to a private doctor instead of an ambulatory, is that on the justification from the doctor there will be the doctor specialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that could do:

> Hello boss, from now on and for an estimate of X months (make a guess for X here) i need to be away for 1/2 hour weekly because of a medical reason

It is really that simple; give your boss the information required and that's it.

Your boss may ask questions but the goal is  to know if you will be suddenly unavailable so to plan for a replacement; something on the line of 'this will not impact on my work because it is unrelated' (only you know if this is a borderline lie...) is usually enough to prevent further questions.

If company culture is not about 'overworking' there is nothing unusual in a colleague with a weekly medical appointment so no loss of esteem or grudge against you because of this; in my opinion this is a drift into overthinking you can safely steer away from.

Source: working in Italy since...ages...

Answer (score 0):

> *I have work permits to use when I need and many hours left to cover my needing,*

I think that answers your question. You have got permission to be away from work, and you have enough time to cover your need, so you can officially be away from work.

If at all, you need to present a reason, you can say (in the order of preference):

- Personal work
- Need to take care of personal meeting
- Medical visit

and that's it. In majority of the cases (if not all), medical information is considered personal and sensitive info and no one usually can / will ask any more details than you're ready to share. Citing the reason should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all familiar with Italian law, but as an American manager of such a person I would prefer if this person could close the door to my private office and confide in me enough of what's going on that I will be able to understand and plan for what I need to know, which is the successful operation of my team, which includes you.  Above all, I don't want to be surprised with a disruption of my team.

And I would also say a couple more things (again, based on my country not necessarily yours).  First:  "anything you might choose to tell me will never leave this room."  And second:  I would direct you to our Human Resources Departments, which might have resources that would be helpful to you and that maybe you weren't aware of.  Within my limits and powers as a manager, I would try to help you.

Also, good luck.  Now speaking as a forum responder, I hope that you successfully resolve the personal issues that you describe.  It can be, as we say, "a tough row to hoe."